# Why is ら attached to り ending adverbs?

Tags: adverbs

First I saw it in a song called ヤミナベ, where it says なべがくるりくるりら回るよ, and I didn't think much of it, since I could only find crayons when I searched it up, then I saw it in a song called マグメル, where it said ぱっぱぱらりら. Before, I didn't ask this question because I researched the ら in na-no adjectives, and I assumed it was that ら. Am I right?

Comment: What do you mean by "the ら in na-no adjectives"? We never say 簡単ら or 緑色ら.

Answer (score 1):

These are songs.  Playing around with sounds is an important part of that.  By way of analogy, we could ask why certain singers of the 1940s and 50s tell us so frequently to do something called "[wop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doo-wop#Origin_of_the_name)".    In short, I suspect that this ら you're hearing is simply an inserted sound that is added because it sounds good and helps with the rhythm and meter. I can find no information about ら added on the end of an adverb and producing another adverb.

Comment: Ok but I still believe there is logic behind it because there are adverbs ending in ら, so I believe its a shortening of the next repeated adverb but ending in ら

Comment: @StarPeep I think you're overthinking. くるりくるりら is just a creative variant of くるり(と) here, and explaining it logically is as difficult as explaining "bibbidi-bobbidi-boo" logically. (ぱっぱ)ぱらりら is a rather common "chant" found in many other songs.